# login system nodejs not working in heroku

Tags: node.js, authentication, heroku

I made a login system that works on my local server with MongoDB connection and do all the work!
but when I deploy it to Heroku it's work until I do register/login the app crash .

````
2020-09-06T05:21:29.834411+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-09-06T05:21:29.834412+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:674:12
2020-09-06T05:21:29.834413+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:567:7) {
2020-09-06T05:21:29.834413+00:00 app[web.1]:   errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
2020-09-06T05:21:29.834414+00:00 app[web.1]:   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
2020-09-06T05:21:29.834414+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-09-06T05:21:30.042423+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stud2emp.herokuapp.com request_id=005e4791-367b-46a7-97e6-0ddb254f0bc6 fwd="93.172.152.146" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=31ms status=304 bytes=276 protocol=https
2020-09-06T05:21:34.085261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/login" host=stud2emp.herokuapp.com request_id=f66c3b5e-e722-4bf0-8905-da9689c9096b fwd="93.172.152.146" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=152 protocol=https
2020-09-06T05:22:07.270229+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/users/login" host=stud2emp.herokuapp.com request_id=9ae52ff0-7cfd-4dde-96eb-cd4a33116b30 fwd="93.172.152.146" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https```
````

Comment: can you share your controller, router, and mongo connection setup. Basically trying to figure out how you're connecting to mongo, and your mongo setup to rule out any issues there.

Comment: make sure your connection strings are changed to the new url in your code and in the mongo gui, also make sure your env variables in heroku are there/correct